# How to know if BLE device is connected currently

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any method like device.isConnected() to know the present state of android BLE device . What I know is I need to implement some architecture like interface from GattclientCallBack class to know if device is connected,but I don't find any method like this. Also the method

```
 mBluetoothGatt.getConnectionState(device);
```

returns int . So exactly how do I know if device is connected ?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `int` returned by `getConnectionState` will be 0, 1, 2, or 3, corresponding to `STATE_DISCONNECTED`, `STATE_CONNECTING`, `STATE_CONNECTED`, or `STATE_DISCONNECTING` respectively. See [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#getConnectionState(android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice)) for more information. Note that this method is only available on API level 18 and higher.

However, the documentation of this method includes the following warning:

> Not supported - please use `getConnectedDevices(int)` with `GATT` as argument

This refers to the method [`BluetoothManager.getConnectedDevices`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getConnectedDevices(int)). The constant value to pass is [`BluetoothProfile.GATT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html#GATT). Again, this method is only available on API level 18 and higher. It sounds like this method will be perfect for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks :) . I always used to wonder like why I am getting 0 as success when my device gets connected,as my general thinking says that 0 could be failure :) I forgot to click on the different device states . So it means if it returns 0 device is connected , am I right ?

Comment: The return value 2 corresponds to connected. I think the int values have been assigned according to the natural flow of states (i.e. a device starts disconnected (0), then must begin connecting (1), then will be connected (2), then will later be disconnected (3)).

Comment: I will recheck and confirm but I think I get 0 as status when device gets connected, in GattclientCallback

Comment: If you're referring to [`onConnectionStateChange`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.html#onConnectionStateChange(android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt,%20int,%20int)) then the `status` should indeed be 0 (indicating success) but the `newState` should be 2 to represent a newly-connected device.

Comment: Yes in onConnectionStateChange status is 0 . :)

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct , the newstate is 2 ,while status is 0 :)